# It is raining heavily

Tags: grammar

> It is raining heavily.
>
> It is raining heavier.

When the rain is getting bigger. Which one state as the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend

> It is raining more heavily now

or

> The rain is getting heavier

From [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparatives-and-superlatives/comparison-adverbs-worse-more-easily) (Cambridge University Press):

> **Adverbs with more and most**
>
> Adverbs with two or more syllables form the comparative and superlative with *more* and *most*:
>
> *We need to treat the environment more carefully*.

Answer (score 0):

> **Heavily is an adverb.** It is qualifying the intensity/amount of rainfall.
>
> **Heavier is an comparative adjective.** It compares a state with another state.

Here, the correct use will be the first one, ie, It is raining heavily. This is a complete sentence itself.

You can use the second one in informal/casual conversation. It is more of a cropped form of : 
*It is now raining heavier than it was earlier.*